# UItableView reloadData reloads table from middle section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

A strange thing. After I call `[tableView reloadData]`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called with `indexPath.section = 6` and not = 0. How can this be, and how can I fix it?

Comment: ReloadData will reload whole table. You are confusing by section no. Just put a nslog in the method and see section no. in gdb. It might possible that you will section no 6 before section 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to reset your tableview to the top and then call reload if you want the display to start from the top.

```
[yourtableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. My "Reset" button was at the bottom of the screen. Looks like reloadData triggers reload of sections of the visible part of the table(until bottom). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it reloads for the current offset.

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of your code . This is by default behavior, execution of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` starts with last section thats 6 in your case and 0 row for that section.

By the way this does not create any kind of problem.

Comment: section 6 is not my last section. The problem is that table reload starts from the middle section instead of the first. Thanks @Praveen for giving me a solution.